# Is there a preferred way to migrate from logcheck to fluentd?

Tags: fluentd

Logcheck uses a negative filter approach, you specify the log messages that you consider harmless and you will see the rest. Looking at fluentd it is the opposite, it will filter messages that are deemed interesting, and show(forward) you those.
Having a considerable set of custom logcheck rules I wonder if there is a migration path (plugin) available to help in the transition.
Ideally that plugin would work with an existing logcheck ruleset and tag the event matched/not-matched.
I have not found any such plugin or guidelines on how to achieve this so far.